# How to keep UI hidden with Immersive mode?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

On my app i use immersive sticky mode on every activity this way:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            |View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainmenu);
}
```

And it works very well, but when I switch between activities buttons and bar show up for a second, and then hide again. Is there any way to keep them hidden all the time?

I'm very new to this, so please explain it simply.

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the visibility of the outer most view hidden in your xml as below,

```js
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone">
</LinearLayout>
```

You can put this visibility property to whichever view you want

Comment: I think i didn't make it obvious... by bar and buttons i meant http://i.imgur.com/TAD9cDT.png android UI. They show and hide after a second and this is very annoying.

Answer (score 0):

try put your code under `onCreate()` after
`setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainmenu);`
it works for me